# Image source with base 64 not showing up using Angular JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, image, base64, arrays

I am displaying images as base 64 from a byte array saved in sql database .

**Here is my html code**

```
      <img id="imgavatar" data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{user.Avatar}}" data-err-src="~/Images/avatar.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute" />

    <img id="imgprofile" data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{user.ProfileImage}}" data-err-src="~/Images/image-icon.png" style="width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute" />
```

Image not showing however the binary numbers are appending with image source as seen in picture

Here is the code which I used to save the image as byte array

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id,string user,HttpPostedFileBase avatar, HttpPostedFileBase profile)
    {
     if (avatar != null)
            {
                p.avatar = new byte[avatar.InputStream.Length];


            }
    }
```

Here is the code for getting the image

```
Avatar = Convert.ToBase64String(profile.avatar),
```

Image not showing up however the string is appending with sourcce

[image]

Need help What I am doing wrong?

Comment: yor data don't look like Base64 encoded string

Comment: Do this : in your controller `user.Avatar = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+user.Avatar;`  then in html `data-ng-src="{{user.Avatar}}"`

Comment: @gauravbhavsar see edit

Comment: this should work http://plnkr.co/edit/C4O2xqAx64RPozg9J8U2?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data it's not Base64 data. Probably its problem in server side.

**For Client:**
Try to use this plugin for angular:
https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload

**For server side**
Here code for convert image to Base64:

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have images as bytes array from httppostedfilebase

Comment: So you need to do this:
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
Then you will have base64 that you need return to client

Comment: You data looks odd.........why it is only '.....AAAAAAAAAAAAA....'???
I think your byte array bad
Here you can check your data - and take base64 for checking http://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/

Comment: Yes I dont know why this is happening my problem is the byte array saving from httppostedfilebase

Comment: You need post more you server side

Comment: Solved it I am missing this  p.avatar = new byte[avatar.InputStream.Length];
                    avatar.InputStream.Read(p.avatar, 0, p.avatar.Length);